# How to find a good point to start a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, fstream

I have a text file of a HUGE amount of words, 20K+, however they are all in alphabetical order, now say you get a random file that you don't know how big it is, how would you find a good starting point to make a well balanced tree? Note: Im doing this in C++. Thank you for any advice! I'm reading them in like this currently:

```
template <typename T>
int BST<T>::loadFromFile(string filename)
{
    int count = 0;
    string tempdata;
    ifstream fin(filename);
    if(!fin)
{
    cout<< "Error: Could no open file\n";
    count--;
}
while(fin)
{
    fin>>tempdata;
    if(fin)
    {
        insertEntry(tempdata);
        cout<<"Word: "<<tempdata<<" Count:"<<count<<endl;
        count++;

    }
}
fin.close();
return count;
}//end of loadFromFile() function
```

^spacing errors, i can never copy my code correctly into questions :P

EDIT: If my insert method words correctly, i do believe after it reads in an alphabetical sorted file it should be one \ line like that because each word is larger than the next.

Comment: 20,000 isn't a huge amount. There is an *O(N)* algorithm to construct a balanced tree from sorted input. Your question remains unclear.

Comment: Wait, is the random file still sorted?  I thought it wasn't.

Comment: Yeah im saying if someone gives me a shorter file that i dont know the length to. How would i find the best root possible from that file?

Comment: Why? A balanced tree algorithm gives you a reasonable approximation to a best root anyway, just by normal construction. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, it's somewhat solved by the answer below. If the file is sorted alphabetically, then my binary search tree would then just be a diagonal line of data, not a tree. Therefore not making it very efficient in searching for data.

Comment: The diagonal line would make the search go through each and every data element, and if there's 100k+ words that would take a normal computer longer than a well balanced tree.

Comment: Your requirement keeps changing from sorted to random and back again, but if you use a balanced-tree algorithm you don't have a problem, and if you sort the input and then use the algorithm I mentioned originally you also don't have a problem. There is therefore no problem left.

Comment: `std::map` is ordered by default and it is done this way for a reason. Use `std::map::find` and be happy.

Answer (score 2):

> all how would you find a good starting point to make a well balanced
>   tree?

Read the file in to a vector v of elements

Sort vector v;

a) load single tree element from middle = (size/2)

b) recurse load from left half (v[0] .. v[middle]-1),

c) recurse load from right half (v[middle + 1] .. v[size()]

delete vector

---

2014-08-02 Update.

Thought I would offer some insight about the 'recursive' nature of transferring the sorted vector contents to the binary tree in a 'good' order .. a non-random order that should leave the (simple binary) tree well balanced when complete.

The worst case insert could leave you with an O(n) search.

A balanced (simple) binary tree is O(log n).

```
     static void buildTree(std::vector< std::string >& v)
        { 
           // validation code ... 

           // create 1st node of tree 
           treeStart = new(TreeNode);
           assert(treeStart);

           // announce
           std::cout << "buildTree(std::vector& v)\n" << std::endl;

           // recurse through vector, invoking insertR() for each element
           buildTreeR(v,
                      0,             // smallest index
                      (v.size()-1)); // biggest index

        }


     // recurse through the vector to determine which element to insert
     static void buildTreeR(std::vector< std::string >& v,
                            size_t si,  size_t bi) // small indx, big indx
        {
           // validation code
           do
           {
              size_t di = bi - si;  // delta index 

              switch (di)
              {

              case 0: // 1 elment
              {
                 treeStart->insertR(v[si]);
              }
              break; 

              case 1: // 2 consecutive elements - i.e. 7-6 = 1,  6 7
              {
                 treeStart->insertR(v[si]);  // left
                 treeStart->insertR(v[bi]);  // right
              }
              break;

              case 2: // 3 consecutive elements - i.e. 3-1 = 2,  1 2 3 
              {
                 size_t m = si + 1;
                 treeStart->insertR(v[m]);   // insert middle

                 treeStart->insertR(v[si]);  // insert left 

                 treeStart->insertR(v[bi]);  // insert right 
              }
              break;               

              default: // 4 or more elements - i.e. 32767-0 = 32767, 
              {
                 size_t delta = (bi - si) / 2;

                 size_t m = si + delta;  // the middle of this range

                 treeStart->insertR(v[m]); // insert middle element 

                 buildTreeR (v, si, m-1);  // recurse on left  
                                           // smallest index thru (middle-1)

                 buildTreeR (v, m+1, bi);  // recurse on right 
                                           // (middle+1) thru biggest index
              }
              break;

              }// switch   

           }while(0);

        } // void buildR(std::vector< std::string >& v, size_t si, size_t bi)
```

---

FYI - On my 7 yr old Dell, g++ v4.8.1, ubuntu 12.04,

performance with 32,767 items, and 152,729 bytes (about 5 bytes per string).

```
  buildTree from vec: 
            duration: 132,013 us
         total bytes: 152,729
```

Also, the sort of this vector was invoked using

```
 std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
 // this resulted in a lexicographic sort, probably what you want



 vector    after sort: 
        sort duration: 25,273 us
          total bytes: 152,729
       sizeof(vector): 12
        vector.size(): 32767
```

Alternatives exist, with more complexity - AVL trees, Red-Black trees, etc. On the other hand, with these you could probably forgo the vector and sort.

(performance results used -O0)

Comment: and this won't take away from the constant O(N) in finding anything correct? it would actually help that stay true?

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me a ^ type shape of a binary search tree?

Comment: @StingRay21 - A binary tree 'search' is O(log n). (not const).
It is also, on average:  O(n) space, O(log n) insert, O(log n) delete and worst case:  O(n) space, O(n) insert, O(n) delete.
I agree that the tree shape would be an inverted v, with the middle of the range of values at the top of the tree. The tree height for 32K elements is 15, so the recursive build is only 15 deep.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly if your data is already sorted you would be better off not using a tree but reading the words to a vector and performing binary search to find the desired words. Binary search has the O(log(n)) complexity just like binary tree. Building a vector has O(n) complexity vs O(n*log(n)) of a tree. Even if the words are not sorted, sorting the array would likely perform better than inserting all the words to a tree. For searching using a sorted vector has the advantage of less of a memory overhead and more cache friendly nature which results in higher performance.